# android Listview not showing anything

Tags: java, android, listview

I am working on a first basic android app as a university project and I have an array list of names. I want it to be put into a `ListView`. The problem I have is nothing appears when I bring in the `ListView`under the xml document. I don't get the basic template for item1, sub item 1 etc.
Then when I set up the array to play in the list view still empty list. Below I have the xml document

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="277dp"
        android:id="@+id/listView" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

then here is the java code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    populateListView();
}

private void populateListView() {
    String[] myItems = {"frank","george","alice", "anna"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main, myItems);
    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you have the same layout `R.layout.main` for two different use.
You set the content view as `setContentView(R.layout.main);` where your `ListView` is but you also use this layout with your adapter as `new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main, myItems);`.
So with your code, you don't have any item layout to display your array `myItems`. You need to create another layout as `R.layout.item_layout` with a `TextView` inside (or use an android layout like `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`) for your adapter.

*Note: to avoid some bugs with `ListView`, you have also to set the **height** to `match_parent` or `fill_parent`*

Answer (score 2):

Try this for your adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= 
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myItems);
```

The adapter has to inflate a TextView. You can make your own TextView (if you want to customize it) in XML.

Then it will be:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= 
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.yourcustomtextview, myItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

The default array adapter in Android takes the layout for the row as the second argument.

Change your `ArrayAdapter` constructor to something like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items)
```